# Recovering an EC2 instance

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, amazon-ec2

I was running an ubuntu EC2 instance for about an year and I lost SSH connectivity to it after installing the latest updates. I was running a Rails application with automated capistrano deployment from Codeship.

The server kept refusing two of my private keys and also key from Codeship which I'm using for Continuous Deployment. I thought the `authorized_keys` file may be corrupted and tried all the ways to recover it. But, I'm not successful. *Fortunately, I have a snapshot that was taken in February.*

Here's what I've tried:

1. I created a snapshot with the latest drive and re-created another volume from it.
2. I created a new instance and mounted the new volume that I've created as `/dev/sdf`.
3. While inspecting the `authorized_keys` file on the drive, it has all the 3 keys I mentioned earlier as is.

So, I can conclude that there are no problems with my keys but something with the SSH configs. Even though, I can create a new instance without any hustle, the main problem is **I've to dump the data from the mysql database** present in that volume. Is that possible? If so, how can I do that with the mounted volume?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've to dump the data from the mysql database present in that volume. Is that possible? If so, how can I do that with the mounted volume?

Yes, that's possible:

- Install `mysql` on the host.
- Stop `mysqld`.
- Either point the `datadir` directive inside the `mysql` config to `/<mountpoint-of-your-old-host/path/to/the/datadir` or remove `/path/to/the/datadir` and symlink `/<mountpoint-of-your-old-host/path/to/the/datadir` to `/path/to/the/datadir`.
- Take care of permissions and ownership etc. while doing this.
- Start `mysqld`, do the dump and profit!
- Hint: Implement a system which does dumps of your databases and important data each minute / hour / day / week automatically and saves these in one, better two, remote locations. If the data is sensitive, encrypt it.

Comment: Thank you so much. And yeah, I created a new automated backup script.

Comment: Glad this helped! :) All the best and good luck with your backups!

Answer (score 0):

If you start an EBS instance, then follow this guide [How to Recover an Unreachable Linux Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5213606968661598)

An EBS EC2 instance is a blessing. What you need to do is :

1. Go to EC2 web console, under EBS - volumes, look for the EBS volume
   attach to the instance. Make sure you shutdown instance before doing
   this.
2. Detach it from the instance-id.
3. Now Attach this volume to another "good" EC2 instance.
4. Go into that "good EC2" instance, mount the drive.

If you are not sure about all this, just create a tiny EC2 instance that start inside EBS, and play it first. And you should also create snapshot(s) for the "bad" EC2 (tag them please) as backup for the original volume.

Since EBS volumes is a network storage, this shouldn't be difficult to mount the MySQL volume and transfer it to new EC2.  What you need to do is a lot more snapshot backup before playing with the mysql volume move.

If you don't have a problem launching instance from the "bad EC2 snapshot", then you should do it.  First launch the instance, then mount the DB volume. Since the configuration are IDENTICAL, you should have no problem get your Mysql running immediately with those data intact. (but again, make more snapshot for all those volume before you try them out)

For difficult part, check out this : [Moving a MySQL Database from One EBS Volume to Another on AWS EC2](https://dunniganp.wordpress.com/2012/11/28/moving-a-mysql-database-from-one-ebs-volume-to-another-on-aws-ec2/) . Just remember to backup!  Since EBS volume are charge in pro-rated way, so don't hesitate to create a few backup (even if the DB span a few hundred GB or TB). You can remove them afterwards and only charged for the period of using those storage.